# How to migrate standalone wear OS app to dependent app

Tags: wear-os

I have released phone app and Wear Os app to play store recently. But I made mistake in specifying standalone settings. My wear os app is dependent on phone app. But I released wear os app with standalone set to "true". Now I want to release another production build where I am going to change standalone settings to false. Is it going to cause any policy violation issues during review process?.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not cause any issues.

Leaving it marked as a standalone app could result in a (temporary) suspension until it's rectified, so the correct action is to update it before that happens.